# How to add trailing slash to fix Angular directive reference

Tags: angularjs, mod-rewrite, iis

We are developing an Angular application and the app is in an IIS virtual directory.

So the url of the app is: `https://domain.com/department/myapp`.

By default, IIS does not add the trailing slash in this url and therefore when `ui-router` added the routing path, it becomes `https://domain.com/department/myapp#/home` instead of `https://domain.com/department/myapp/#/home`.

It works fine in latest browsers, but for IE9 it causes a problem.

All my directives are asking for template from a relative url. Without the trailing slash before the `#` character, the `templateUrl` in the directive declaration failed to obtain the template html.

---

Yesterday I thought I could add the trailing slash by doing some url rewrite in IIS. So in my `Web.Config`, I added:

```
<defaultDocument enabled="false"></defaultDocument>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Of course, I also installed `urlrewrite2` on my IIS.

The result? This rewrite rule breaks my link to minified js and css bundles. While all I need is to get the reference to my `app` folder correct.

---

Now I am sitting down and tried to find a proper way to fix it.

Probably need to update the `match url` of the rule to selectively avoid damaging my reference to those bundles?

Is it possible to add the trailing slash on the client side by AngularJS $location service?

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Here is what I've found so far.

The solution is related to neither url rewrite nor angular `$location` service. I added a url check and redirect in `Global.asax` `Application_BeginRequest()`.

Here is the code:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (!NeedToProcess(Request.ApplicationPath, Request.Path)) return;
        var redirectPath = VirtualPathUtility.AppendTrailingSlash(Request.ApplicationPath);
        Response.RedirectPermanent(redirectPath);
    }

    private static bool NeedToProcess(string appPath, string reqPath)
    {
        return appPath != null &&
               appPath != "/" &&
               appPath.Equals(reqPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
```

If anyone have better solution, please feel free to add here.